# ArrayList to string, not to StringArray

Tags: java, android

I'm loading my pictures with Picasso into recyclerview. The user can delete a picture.

In my Database it looks like this:

```
USER     |   IMAGELINK 
the user | www.image.de/image1;www.image.de/image2
```

I split this links in java and populate it into recylerview, it's working.
And deleting works too. But my problem is that I have to delete it from the list and update the database with the string where the deleted image is not in there.

So I do it like this:

```
List<String> delete = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0 ; i < list.size(); i++){
    delete.add(list.get(i).getImageURL());
}

delete.remove(position);

List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < delete.size();i++){
        strings.add(delete.get(i));
}
CharSequence[] cs = strings.toArray(new CharSequence[strings.size()]);
```

The problem is, that it puts in the database a new line, and the pictures are not loaded. I think that comes from the conversion from array to string.

At the moment when I delete a picture it looks like this:

```
USER     |   IMAGELINK 
the user | www.image.de/image1;
www.image.de/image2
```

---

```
Arrays.toString(cs).replace(",",";").replace("[","").replace("]","")
```

Is there any easier solution to convert it to a string to send it to the database?

Comment: please format your code properly and avoid using those snippets as it's intended for javascript code, html markup, css rules and not java code.

Comment: Is `[String.join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-) what you're after?

Comment: @Aomine, I would if formating would work properly, but it's not.

Comment: khelwood I will look, thansk

Comment: @khelwood I can't use it, because it is required sdk 26 and I want to use 21

Answer (score 0):

```
    int userIndex = 777;
    int removeImageIndex = 3;

    String[] images = list.get(userIndex).getImageURL().split(";");
    CharSequence[] cs = new CharSequence[images.length - 1];
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < images.length; i++)
        if (i != removeImageIndex) cs[j++] = images[i];
```